# Create apache.mailet.Mail instance with from File while keeping SMTP RCPT TO and MAIL FROM

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am attempting to create an apache.mailet.Mail instance that is loaded from a file. Previous Implementations of this use MimeMessage together with an Inputstream, but from what I can tell this gets rid of SMTP Information such as MAIL FROM and RCPT TO, which I need to work with as well.
How would I go about this?

This is the current Implementation, which seemingly removes the SMTP RCPT TO/MAIL FROM:

```
public MimeMessage loadEmailFromFile(String testmail) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(testmail);
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    Mail mail = MailImpl.fromMimeMessage(msg.getHeader("Subject")[0], msg);
}
```